# Usage of method setSinCos in Matrix?

Tags: android, matrix

How we can use method `setSinCos(float, float)`?Android Documents say:

> Set the matrix to rotate by the specified sine and cosine values.

But it is ambiguous.For example I do not know role of sine and cosine values.I search in Google,but finally I found some usage of this method,without any comment.Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rotate (counter-clockwise) homogeneous coordinates by an arbitrary angle a, the transformation matrix is:

```
[ cos(a)  -sin(a)  0 ]
[ sin(a)   cos(a)  0 ]
[   0        0     1 ]
```

In the event that you have the result of sin/cos, setSinCos(s, c) will create the following matrix:

```
[ c  -s  0 ]
[ s   c  0 ]
[ 0   0  1 ]
```

You may ask yourself, why?  Well, consider the case where you would like to rotate a sprite to an arbitrary angle determined by the slope between two points.  You could determine the angle by using arctan or arccos, do some checks to make sure you are in the right quadrant, and then supply the new angle to setRotate().  **But why, when you already have the values of sin/cos without needing the angle (sin=dy/dist, cos=dx/dist)?**

`setSinCos` fulfills that need, which is easier on the programmer, as well as more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The question was not so plain, e.g. what if I pass values over 1?
Android manual says nothing, but it's simple to find out that no check for "true" sine/cosine done. Just used the transform matrix that 'Dan' mentioned above.
So in general case one not only rotates but scales in the same time.
I guess that is not bug but undocumented feature.